# BitTorrent Peer Wire messages in C++

Tags: c++, p2p, bittorrent

I am developing a torrent client using C++.
I can't understand the structure of the messages with the peers.
How can I create a simple handshake message using C++ and how can i read the response?
The problem is the structure of the data I have to send and then the structure I have to read.
I want to send to the seed a handshake message sending a BlockBuf for Example.
How i have to create the content of the BlockBuf?
The problem is the structure I have to use for the messages and not the peer to peer connection.... :(

Comment: There are multiple questions you are asking without showing any code that defines why this is a problem, please post your code.

Comment: I am developing the torrent app while i am in the army.Now I have a day off and i dont have the development computer home so i dont have at the momment available code.Also i dont have access to the internet while i am in the army!:P So i think this is a deadlock and i cannot post any code !  The main question is an example of a handshake message written in  C++.

Comment: Which section of the BitTorrent spec is not clear?  The peer messages have a fairly simple structure - it's not difficult to define a class to hold the data and generate a stream from it.

Comment: ..or, when receiving, push bytes into an instance until the protocol unit is complete.

Comment: I cannot understand the message flow.For example a handshake message like this.|char:19||char[19]BitTorrent protocol|long:reserved|char[20]:hash|char[20]:peer_id| is correct? I have these values is a BlockBuf variable.And i have also a struct that is a View to this BlockBuf in order to modify parts of the BlockBuf.

Answer (score 6):

So the [BitTorrent handshake](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html) is comprised of, in order:

1. a byte with value 19 (the length of the string that follows);
2. the UTF-8 string "BitTorrent protocol" (which is the same as in ASCII);
3. eight reserved bytes used to mark extensions;
4. the 20 bytes of the torrent info hash;
5. the 20 bytes of the peer ID.

So, you could start by obtaining a buffer large enough for the handshake message:

```
const int handshake_size = 1+19+8+20+20;
char handshake[handshake_size];
```

Calculating the offsets beforehand also helps:

```
const int protocol_name_offset = 1;
const int reserved_offset = protocol_name_offset + 19;
const int info_hash_offset = reserved_offset + 8;
const int peer_id_offset = info_hash_offset + 20;
```

And then you just have to fill it up.

```
const char prefix = 19;
const std::string BitTorrent_protocol = "BitTorrent protocol";

handshake[0] = prefix; // length prefix of the string
std::copy(BitTorrent_protocol.begin(), BitTorrent_protocol.end(),
          &handshake[protocol_name_offset]); // protocol name
```

And so on for the rest of the data.

Then the buffer can be sent directly to whatever networking API you'll be using.

To read the reply, you extract the parts of the buffer and validate accordingly:

```
if(reply[0] != prefix) {
    // fail
}
if(!std::equal(BitTorrent_protocol.begin(), BitTorrent_protocol.end(), &reply[protocol_name_offset]) {
    // fail 
}
```

And so on.

Reading and writing structures directly from the network is not recommended because you need full control of the layout, or the message will be malformed.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer!Your implementation is similar to mine!After sending that message what response do you get from a torrent client?

Comment: @nikosdi that's described in the specification: the reply is another message with the same format.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Nice tip to calculate offsets. Voted up.